# Wordpress Portfolio: Featured Image inline with title and meta

Tags: php, css, wordpress, post, portfolio

First of all, I'm fairly inexperienced - especially with PHP. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to customize Wordpress portfolio post pages. I want the post titles and meta to appear inline and to the right of the featured images.

I've tried to accomplish this with pure CSS, adding "display:inline-block" and floats the image and title. This isn't working, so I am assuming I need to edit the php template (content-portfolio.php), but can't figure out what to do.

Again, any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

The content-portfolio.php file as it exists now is:

```
<?php

// =============================================================================
// VIEWS/INTEGRITY/CONTENT-PORTFOLIO.PHP
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Portfolio post output for Integrity.
// =============================================================================

$archive_share = x_get_option( 'x_integrity_portfolio_archive_post_sharing_enable' );

?>



<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
  <div class="entry-featured">
    <?php x_portfolio_item_featured_content(); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="entry-wrap cf">

    <?php if ( x_is_portfolio_item() ) : ?>

      <div class="entry-info">
        <header class="entry-header">
          <h1 class="entry-title entry-title-portfolio"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
          <?php x_integrity_entry_meta(); ?>
        </header>
        <?php x_get_view( 'global', '_content', 'the-content' ); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="entry-extra">
        <?php x_portfolio_item_tags(); ?>
        <?php x_portfolio_item_project_link(); ?>
        <?php x_portfolio_item_social(); ?>
      </div>


     <?php else : ?>

      <header class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title entry-title-portfolio">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to: "%s"', '__x__' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>"><?php x_the_alternate_title(); ?></a>
        </h2>
      </header>
        <?php x_get_view( 'global', '_content' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if what you mean is having both in the h1 line:

```
<h1 class="entry-title entry-title-portfolio"><?php the_title(); x_integrity_entry_meta();?></h1>
```

you can also try changing the **entry-header** style to `.entry-header{display:flex}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried this and it made the meta inline with the title, but not the image. I may not have properly explained what I am trying to achieve. A good example can be seen here: https://medium.com/s/trustissues/yes-the-media-still-matters-6bbd4ce1b860. The post title and info is next to the image. Any idea how I can achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Well what you say now was the information needed in the question, so if you see the next image, you will see there is a parent div (green) which contains 2 children (red and orange) this parent has the flex property applied as I mentioned before, and depending of the contents it will align as desired, here is a picture of what I mean talking about colors https://box.magc.co/index.php/s/OpxnQaR8EGhfS0F

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure css.

You need assign a specific width to the header ".entry-header".

And also assign "display:inline" both to ".entry-title-portfolio" and to the tag that wrap your meta content.

```
header.entry-header { width: 100%; }
h1.entry-title-portfolio { display: inline; }
[your meta class] { display: inline; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried this code, but it didn't change anything. I may not have properly explained what I am trying to achieve - an example can be seen here: medium.com/s/trustissues/…. The post title and info are next to the image. Any idea what else I could try? Thanks again!